# How to auto answer linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, python-3.6

My code is

```
import os
os.popen("yaourt -S git",'w').write(mypass)
```

But after question is "do you want install [y/n]". How can I automaticaly answer to question? I want Whenever the terminal asks a question, my answer is be "y".

[image]

Comment: Option `--noconfirm` to yaourt should do the trick

Comment: Thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following to your command:

```
yaourt -S git --noconfirm
```

It makes sure that confirmation is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.yaourtrc` file in your home directory:

```
cp /etc/yaourtrc ~/.yaourtrc
```

And edit the following lines:

```
BUILD_NOCONFIRM=1
EDITFILES=0
```

Then `yaourt` won't ask you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the `yes` unix command.

`os.system("yes y")`
or
`os.system("yes y")` if uppercase Y is needed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)